# Adding an un-ordered list

Tags: html, unordered

I'm basically moving the page links to the left side of the site and I want them to be in a un ordered list form, I just can't understand where to place the `<ul> <li>`

Trying to add an un ordered list to:

```
<div id="left">
    <b><a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="listing.html">Listing</a>
    <a href="financing.html">Financing</a>
    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    </b>
</div>
```

FULL Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
   <title>Prime Properties</title>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="prime.css" />

</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<h1><img alt="PRIMELOGO" src="primelogo.gif" width="650" height="100" /></h1>
<p>Prime Properties is prepared to market and sell your property.<br /><br />The philosophy of Prime Properties is to promote our clients, not ourselves.<br /><br />We can also help you find the property that meets your needs:</p>
<ul>
<li>location</li>
<li>price</li>
<li>features</li>
</ul>
<div id="contact"><b>Prime Properties<br />3055 Bode Road<br />Schaumburg, IL 60194<br /><br />847-555-5555</b></div>
&nbsp;
<div id="footer">
<div id="left"><b><a href="index.html">Home</a> <a href="listing.html">Listing</a> <a href="financing.html">Financing</a> <a href="contact.html">Contact</a></b></div>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p>&copy; Copyright "xxxxx" xxxxxxx 2012<br /> <a href="mailto:xxxxxxx@gmail.com">xxxxxxxx@gmail.com</a></p>
</div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're wanting something like this as shown in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wt4Js/)

```
<style>
    div#left ul{list-style:none;font-weight:bold;}
    div#left ul li{display:inline-block;}
</style>

<div id="left">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="listing.html">Listing</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="financing.html">Financing</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It give's 1 error on html validation :

Element style not allowed as child of element div in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

Comment: lol, the ```<style>``` declarations should be in an external CSS file or in the least contained within the ```head``` section. I merely listed it here for brevity. Move the ```style``` into head and it will validate fine.